# Reading the first line of a text file in Android Java(API17)

Tags: java, android

I'm really new in Java and I'm trying to figure out how to read a line from .txt file in SD card. The code below doesn't seem to work since it returns an empty result.

```
public static final String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

public static String getProfileInfo() {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        File unzippedText = new File(filePath + "profile.txt");
        BufferedReader text = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(unzippedText));
        sb.append(line);
        text.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: does my answer help? If so please accept

Answer (score 1):

This code is not going to do anything

```
sb.append(line);
```

line is still equal to ""

try reading using the `BufferedReader.readLine`

```
line = text.readLine (); // first line only
```